# How to remove the reports section conditionally from buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want the the ability to remove the `reports` section from `buildspec.yml` when deploying to PROD:

```
reports
 TotalCoverageReport:
   files:
     - 'reports/coverage.xml'
```

It should only run the above if in DEV.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you will need to use two different `buildspec.yml`, or "manually" run the tests without relying on CB.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll try the separate buildspec.yml

Comment: @Marcin Could you please add this as an answer to help someone else I tested it and it's working. I have two files `buildspec-dev.yml` and `buildspec-prod.yml`

Comment: Thanks. Answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution is to use **different** `buildspec` file depending on the environment. The default name is `buildspec.yml`, but you can have multiple ones in you project and you can [overwrite the default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage) one to use alternative as needed, e.g. `buildspec-prod.yml` or `buildspec-dev.yml`.